# Display PageList in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have written the code below. I want to display the page list and foreign keys of table.

Please help me solve this confusing problem since I only have 1 view().

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Authors)
                      .Include(b => b.BookTypes)
                     .Include(b => b.Categories)
           .Include(b => b.Publishers).ToList();
    var model = db.Books.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);

    return View(books);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 var list = db.Books.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();
 int pageSize = 10;
 int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

 return View(list.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```